# AWS Amplify Datastore AppSync not synchronize IndexDB with DynamoDB

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js). It worked just fine before I updated aws-amplify to v3.3.26. After the update it stopped to synchronize IndexDB with DynamoDB. I didn't have any errors when I set `Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'`.

After tutorial in `main.ts` I had:

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import {DataStore} from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

After that I pulled data from Amplify UI I got generated GraphQl Models and src/aws-exports.js

````
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "REGION",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "REGION",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "REGION:xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "REGION",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "REGION_xxxxxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket": "BUCKET",
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_content_delivery_url": "http://BUCKET.s3-website.REGION.amazonaws.com"
};```

And I tried to update data like this:
````

await DataStore.save(User.copyOf(data, (item:MutableModel) => {
item.phone = data.phone;
}));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix it I changed `main.ts` to this:

src/main.ts

```
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'
import PubSub from '@aws-amplify/pubsub';
import API from '@aws-amplify/api';
import Amplify, { Logger } from 'aws-amplify';
import {DataStore} from '@aws-amplify/datastore';

API.configure(awsconfig);
PubSub.configure(awsconfig);
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
DataStore.configure(awsconfig);
Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR';
DataStore.start();
```

And now I need to have subscription to Model changes any time I edit data.

src/app/user/edit-user.component.ts

```
import {DataStore} from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import {User} from '../models';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-page',
  templateUrl: './edit-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-page.component.scss']
})
export class EditPageComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = DataStore.observe<User>(User).subscribe(() => {});
  }
  async update(data) {
    await DataStore.save(User.copyOf(data, (item:MutableModel<User>) => {
      item.phone = data.phone;
    }));
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```